# In WordPress 3.0.1, my categories box is not showing up in the post edit screen?

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, categories

I'm setting up WordPress for a client. It's version 3.0.1.

As I'm setting things up, it seems now that the category box (where you select the category you want the post to go into) doesn't show up in the post edit page? It was most definitely there before, but now it is not. I'm not sure what's happened?

I even reinstalled the whole thing to see if that's helped. And it did for a bit, only for the category select box to now be gone again. I can do a QuickEdit and select the categories there, but it's not on the main edit page.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: The categories box (#categorydiv) is there, but it has display: none set to it. Though it didn't at first. I modded the WordPress admin stylesheet to have a display: block !important and this has shown it correctly. This isn't an answer to it though... I need to know the proper problem with this.

Comment: Can you give me an account with authoring/contributing permissions in order to check it out? Sounds odd but might be something tiny and catchy.

Answer (score 1):

While in edit post/page view, check your Screen Options, it's a hanging tab under the header.
You may have the "Show categories" checkbox off.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Panels#Screen_Options

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It doesn't seem to be this... It's sometimes there and sometimes not. It's mostly there when I start a fresh project, and as I develop my template, I realise it's then gone. Odd, I just cannot explain it reliably!

Comment: does it come back if you change your active theme to the default one?